# customize and pack a debian image

Tags: linux, debian

Given a vanilla Debian I need to:

- pick a filesystem
- configure the software ( writing .conf files and edit shell scripts )
- install/remove packages
- install/remove software compiled by me

After that I'd like to pack everything in a working .iso/.img. Are there good tools that will do this? I basically need to create something like a firmware starting from Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [os4systemimage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/os4systemimage/) (fork of now defunct [remastersys](http://souceforge.net/projects/remastersys/))

It is CLI though there is a GUI but [that's work in progress](http://system-imaging.blogspot.com/2013/08/remastersys-system-imager-source-code.html)